# Is it possible to specify specific different fonts for different languages in GVIM 8.2?

Tags: fonts, gvim

**My GVim 8.2**

[image: IMG:]

I am using Traditional Chinese Windows 10

I am trying to set up my GVim 8.2 to use a choice of font for Chinese language and then a
different font for English, because of my preference.

How do I do that? If there is something I can do to ask this question better, please
let me know.

In my .vimrc,  I have this right now added to the default content of the installation:

```
set langmenu=en_US
let $LANG = 'en_US'
source $VIMRUNTIME/delmenu.vim
source $VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim
set guifont=Consolas:h12:cANSI:qDRAFT
```

Comment: I am trying this, but this gives me an error

Comment: set guifontwide=guifont=細明體:h12:cCHINESEBIG5:qDRAFT
set guifont=Consolas:h12:cANSI:qDRAFT

Comment: I think the comments should have been added to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out this is all you need:

```
set guifontwide=細明體:h12:cCHINESEBIG5:qDRAFT
set guifont=Consolas:h12:cANSI:qDRAFT
```